# Tiny Encryption Algorithm in game engine

Tags: c, encryption

After being warned that my simple rotation encryption wouldn't be enough for my game, I decided to look around for some good, simple alternatives. I found a simple looking TEA example [here](http://143.53.36.235:8080/source.htm#ansi) I plugged it into my game engine.

```
    void encipher(unsigned long *const v,unsigned long *const w,
   const unsigned long *const k)
{
   register unsigned long       y=v[0],z=v[1],sum=0,delta=0x9E3779B9,
                a=k[0],b=k[1],c=k[2],d=k[3],n=32;

   while(n-->0)
      {
      sum += delta;
      y += (z << 4)+a ^ z+sum ^ (z >> 5)+b;
      z += (y << 4)+c ^ y+sum ^ (y >> 5)+d;
      }

   w[0]=y; w[1]=z;
}
```

I try to plug in some numbers into it but an error is popping up:

```
Cast loses const qualifier
```

wondering If anyone knew what this means?

Comment: If you are looking at simple encryption algorithms then RC4 is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
unsigned long *const v
```

Use this instead:

```
unsigned long const *v
```

Comment: hmmm maybe I'll just try to make TEA myself and stay away from this haha